# Which resx file is accessed?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In a DLL library used by an MVC application I've got the following line of code:

```
AccountResource.ResourceManager.GetString("key")
```

But I have many Resource file. About one per each page of the website. Which of the N *.resx file will be searched to find if it contains the specified key?

Comment: Well, since you're accessing the `ResourceManager` of `AccountResource`, I'd say it uses `AccountResource.resx`.

Comment: Thanks.. I looked the class structure and I got confused since it's generated and I thought for error it was part of the framework :D.. however I think your answer may be useful also for beginner developer.. answer and I will accept...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're accessing `AccountResource.resx`. `.ResourceManager` is a static property of `AccountResource`, returning a `ResourceManager` instance. Try hovering over the property, you'll see this in the tooltip:

> Returns the cached ResourceManager instance used by this class.